# how to resize video on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to resize the video when I click on it. The video should become larger (about 3/4 of the page size). How can this be implemented so that it does not look clumsy.
html div

```
``<div class="flower_petal flower_petal_small flower_petal_video">
                                <div class="flower_petal_video_video">
                                    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/xxx/xxx" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div> ``
    

css
 ``.flower_petal_video {
  margin: -60px 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 268px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  background-image: url(../img/laptop.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0000;
}
 
.flower_petal_video_video {
  /*background-color: #f00;*/
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  margin: 15.4%;  ``
```

Comment: Checkout CSS Transitions: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 1):

To get your "click" event on the youtube iframe, I'd use the youtube iframe api (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Then I'd add a "playing" class to your iframe container when the video is playing, and remove it when it's paused.

Then you can use the "playing" class to change the size of your video.

```html
<div class="flower_petal flower_petal_small flower_petal_video">
  <div class="flower_petal_video_video">
    <div id="youtubePlayer">
      <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var youtubePlayer = document.getElementById("youtubePlayer");
  var player = new YT.Player("player", {
    videoId: "wuJIqmha2Hk",
    events: {
      onStateChange: function (event) {
        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
          youtubePlayer.classList.add("playing");
        }

        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
          youtubePlayer.classList.remove("playing");
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.flower_petal_video_video {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

#youtubePlayer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

#youtubePlayer.playing {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
}

#player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/AliKlein/pen/PoWMdLg)

Answer (score 0):

use this html and javascript

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
        video.onclick = function(){
            video.style.height = "75%"
            video.style.width = "75%"
        }
```

```html
 <video controls width="300" height="300" class="video" id="video" autoplay disablepictureinpicture tabindex="-1">
        <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1rAHEQPrg1nY0xC3Q0UgVuqSgVWvFiY0a" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Comment: I need the video to grow along with the block to which it is attached (there is a background)

Answer (score 0):

You can operate width and height here:

```js
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/xxx/xxx" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```